# Как передать экземпляр класса JS на другую HTML-страницу?

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть 2-х страничный сайт, где на первой странице находиться форма, которую заполняет пользователь. Я создал класс, полями которого являются значения полей, вводимых пользователем (Имя, фамилия и т.д.). Экземпляры этого класса должны передаваться на другую страницу в виде массива.
Я бы мог использовать sessionStorage, но он не хочет работать с пользовательскими типами данных?
Что мне делать?

Comment: > Я бы мог использовать sessionStorage, но он не хочет работать с пользовательскими типами данных? Но массив-то в JSON-формате можно передать.

Comment: Передать экземпляр, да и какую либо переменную с одной сраницы на другую не получится. Придется сохранять значения на одной странице, записывать их куда то, а на другой считывать их. Еще как вариант из 2-х страниц сделать одну. Заполнение данных вынести в виде попапчика, к примеру.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, что бы передать пользовательский тип данных можно использовать JSON-формат, с которым sessionStorage работает.

На первой странице:

```
let json = JSON.stringify(users);
sessionStorage.setItem('test', json);
```

На второй странице:

```
let json2 = sessionStorage.getItem('test');
let users2 = JSON.parse(json2)
```

Answer (score 0):

IndexedDB -  может хранить почти любое значение, в том числе сложные объекты.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Показал бы пример. Как сохранять... Как читать...